# error: cannot find symbol method onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase)

Tags: android, sqlite, backwards-compatibility

I am trying to make my app backward compatible.
I went through whole development process targeting SDK version 22:

```
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 22
```

So now, after I am satisfied with my app, I want to make it work on older phones. I decided to try to make it work on API level 8 so I edited build.gradle:

```
minSdkVersion 8
targetSdkVersion 8
```

And after changing whole lot of stuff in code, I hit this dbhelper problem I cannot resolve:

> Error:(72, 14) error: cannot find symbol method onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase)

So, after trying to find how to resolve this, I think I should somehow import com.twofortyfouram.memento.provider.sqlite.SqliteOpenHelperCompat but I don't know where to get it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the method `onConfigure` exists and is defined on the API you are now targeting?

From what I can see from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onConfigure(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)) the method was defined on API 16.

Also, how can you set a minSdkVersion 14 and targetSdkVersion 8?

`You are basically saying that my application can only work from APIs of version 14 and above, but I am targeting version 8`

Comment: Nope, it did not resolve my problem, just pointed to my absence of mind :)

Comment: Did you try commenting out the onConfigure method? It probably does not exist on your sdk version since it was created on version 16

Comment: Okay, onConfigure does not exist on API level 8 FROYO but how can I overcome this? I don't know if I even need this override:
`public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onConfigure(db);
        db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
}`

Comment: This has to be removed. The setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled method is also defined in version 16 and you cannot use that, just remove the whole onConfigure method

Comment: Thanx, you can edit the accepted answer to primarily indicate that override should be deleted, which I just did.